# How Can I Close the program when it's full?

Tags: c#

```
 string[,] Arr = new string[4, 5]{{"1A" , " 2A" , " 3A" , " 4A" , " 5A"},
    {"1B" , " 2B" , " 3B" , " 4B" , " 5B"},
    {"1C" , " 2C" , " 3C" , " 4C" , " 5C"},
    {"1D" , " 2D" , " 3D" , " 4D" , " 5D"}};

        Console.WriteLine("List of availabe seats.");
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int j = 0; j < Arr.Length; j++)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < Arr.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < Arr.GetLength(1); k++)
                {
                    Console.Write(Arr[i, k]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter your seat: ");
            Console.WriteLine("---------------- ");
            string textToReplace = Console.ReadLine().ToLowerInvariant();
            bool isFullyBooked = true;
            bool isSeatTaken = true;
            for (int row = Arr.GetLowerBound(0); row <= Arr.GetUpperBound(0); ++row)
            {
                for (int column = Arr.GetLowerBound(1); column <= Arr.GetUpperBound(1); ++column)
                {
                    if (Arr[row, column].ToLowerInvariant().Contains(textToReplace))
                    {
                        Arr[row, column] = " X ";
                        isSeatTaken = false;
                    }
                    if (!Arr[row, column].Contains(" X "))
                    {
                        isFullyBooked = false;
                    }
                }


            }
            if (isFullyBooked)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fully Booked");
                Console.WriteLine("----------------");
            }
            if (isSeatTaken)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Already Taken");
                Console.WriteLine("----------------");
            }
        }
```

How can I close the program when it's full? If I run this program it ended up 20 loops only so if I input two "2A" the program will not complete all seats and the program will close. Im a begginer in c#.

Comment: *Decompose* your implementation: let `Arr` be a *private field*, add *property* or *method* `IsFullyBooked` as well as `IsSeatTaken(String seat)`...

Comment: Also Make Arr be a `Seat[,]` or `List<Seat>` (I.e make your own seat class)

Comment: @Sayse: I'd rather use `Dictionary<String, Boolean> Arr`: key is the seat and value if the seat is taken or not

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - My problem with that is it would break if two seats had the same seat number (such as `1A` existing on a lower tier and a balcony)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need "quick and dirty" solution then move your `fullyBooked` variable declaration outside of main for-loop, and change that for-loop from `for (int j = 0; j < Arr.Length; j++)` to something like

```
bool isFullyBooked = false;
while (!isFullyBooked)
{
  // rest of your code, but change bool isFullyBooked = true; 
  // to simply isFullyBooked = true; without declaration, only assignment
  // because it was declared earlier
```

So your main loop will run until all seats are booked.

But again - it very "quick and dirty" fix, consider to refactor your implementation as it doesn't looks very good. ( I suppose it's slightly off-topic here, and subject to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) )